# dictionaryの合計値の算出方法について

Tags: c#, linq

```
Dictionary<string, classA>()

classA{
 int AAA,
 int BBB
}
```

上記のようなディクショナリーをlinqのconcatにてそれぞれの値を合計することはできますでしょうか。

例えば・・・
dicA {string: "C", classA {AAA:1, BBB:2}}
dicB {string: "C", classA {AAA:3, BBB:4}}

上記のようにキーが同一のディクショナリーに対し、

```
dicA.concat(dicB).GroupBy(e => e.Key, c => c.Value).～
```

として、
dicAの結果が
dicA {string: "C", classA {AAA:4, BBB:6}}

とすることが理想です。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

本家SOの[類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2812545)にある[解決済みの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2812572)と同様の解法です。

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class classA
    {
        public int AAA;
        public int BBB;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dicA = new Dictionary<string, classA> { { "C", new classA { AAA = 1, BBB = 2 } } };
            var dicB = new Dictionary<string, classA> { { "C", new classA { AAA = 3, BBB = 4 } } };

            // メソッド版
            dicA = dicA.Concat(dicB).GroupBy(e => e.Key).Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, AAA = g.Sum(p => p.Value.AAA), BBB = g.Sum(p => p.Value.BBB) })
                .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => new classA { AAA = item.AAA, BBB = item.BBB });
            // クエリ版
            dicA = (from e in dicA.Concat(dicB)
                    group e by e.Key into g
                    select new { Key = g.Key, AAA = g.Sum(p => p.Value.AAA), BBB = g.Sum(p => p.Value.BBB) })
                .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => new classA { AAA = item.AAA, BBB = item.BBB });

            foreach (var p in dicA)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: AAA = {1}, BBB = {2}", p.Key, p.Value.AAA, p.Value.BBB));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

メソッド版とクエリ版は全く同一の処理をしています。
なので、そのまま実行すると`dicA`に`dicB`を2回足して下記の結果が出力されます。
`C: AAA = 7, BBB = 10`

上記の版を片方削除すれば求める値を取得できます。
ただし本家SO回答の注釈の通り、2つのDictionaryをIEnumerableとして集計し、新しいclassAを生成しているため、処理の効率が優れている訳ではありませんのでご留意願います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。まさに知りたかった内容です。処理の効率が優れているわけではないとのことですので、処理速度を確認してみます。